# Inconsistent styling in latex table of contents?

Tags: latex, tableofcontents

I'm wondering why in my toc shown below, I have different dots style in the most detailed subsections ?

[image]

All I've used is:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
....
\tableofcontents
```

How can I create a consistent style at all levels of depth: section, subsection, etc?

Comment: What is the context of these counters - the Latex example book? DocBook? something else?  What packages are you using in your document?

Comment: \usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}

Comment: I'm using this packages above. I'm writing the thesis actually.

Comment: Sorry I can't take this further.  I also have a problem with the ToC. The ToC label in the header is always in uppercase, rather than the input case.  I have not found any way to change what the ToC does in regard to either question. I hope any answers to your question will take me further with mine. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on the document class you are using; book, article etc have a preset layout for the TOC.

Since you said you are writing your Thesis, is it possible that you are using a style given by the college/university?

There is still a way to change it. You can use the package tocloft,

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
```

which has a method called \@dotsep to change the amount of space between the dots. Although I do not know if it will work in this case as you only define it once for the whole TOC and if it is relative to what you have it may just increase your dots relative to the way it is already placed.

But here is the code anyways,

```
\makeatletter \renewcommand{\@dotsep}{4.5} \makeatother
\tableofcontents
```

It must be placed before your toc command and 4.5 represents the distance.

But like I said this depends on your document class and its style class. Here is the link to the package documentation [tocloft.pdf](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf). There are more customizations available which may work for you better.

Comment: Thanks for the clue. I had to actually set something like that in my custom style file: \renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdot}}

Comment: Yes, there were quite a few customizations and I wasn't sure what document class you were using so I just picked the most obvious option which was dotsep but I'm glad it worked out

Answer (score 2):

At least in the article class, they already have a standard style, but to also get dot leaders for sections like the ones in subsections, just use this:

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}
```